# Form to PHP_SELF but does not pass post values

Tags: php, forms, iis, pdo, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a "report" that can be filtered using a form on the top of the page. The options to filter the results is the Fiscal Year which is the current FY by default and multiple categories (check boxes) which are all checked by default. The page generates properly with the default data but when the form is submitted the page will "refresh" but there is no POST data generated. I tried creating a copy of the page and setting it as the action URL but it still did not have any POST data and used the defaults. I will include my code below and will try to narrow it down to just the necessary parts to make it easier but can share all of it if need be. Thank you in advance for any help offered.

```
<body>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo"SET";} else{echo"NOT SET";}
// Establish Connection and Variables       
// Connection   
        include "./include/class/DBConnection.php";
        DBConnection::$dsn;
        DBConnection::$user;
        DBConnection::$pass;
        DBConnection::getDBConnection();
// The Current Fiscal Year
        $today = getdate();
        $month = $today['month'];
        // seperate first and second half of fiscal year
        $old = array('January','February','March','April','May','June');    
        if (in_array($month,$old)) {
            $year = $today['year'] + 1;
        }
        else {
            $year = $today['year'];
        }                       
// Create SQL Query Variables - Removed for post
// Set filter criteria
// Retrieve array of possible categories and create SQL WHERE statment  
        $catAllCxn = DBConnection::$cxn->prepare($SQL_Categories);
        $catAllCxn->execute();
        $catAllCxn->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $catAllArray = array();
        while($catAllRow = $catAllCxn->fetch()) {
            $cat = $catAllRow['Category'];
            array_push($catAllArray, $cat);
        }
        $catAllInQuery = implode(',',array_fill(0,count($catAllArray),'?'));
// Create array for category filter IF form was submitted to itself
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){  // if page is submitted to itself

            $catFilterArray = $_POST['Category'];
            $catFilterInQuery = implode(',',array_fill(0,count($catFilterArray),'?'));

        }
// Switch for ALL or Filtered report
        if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if page is not submitted to itself 

            $FiscalYear = $year;
        //  $DiscludedDepartmentNumbers = "21117";
            $catArray = $catAllArray;
            $IncludedCategories = $catAllInQuery;
        }
        else {
            $FiscalYear = $_POST["FiscalYear"];
        //  $DiscludedDepartmentNumbers = "21117";
            $catArray = $catFilterArray;
            $IncludedCategories = $catFilterInQuery;
        }               
    ?>
<!-- Filter Form -->        
    <div id="filters" style="border: 1px solid;"> 
        <form name="filter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST"> 
            Fiscal Year: <input type="text" name="FiscalYear" value="<?php echo $FiscalYear; ?>" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo"SET";} else{echo"NOT SET";}?>
            <br />
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Select Categories</legend>
                <?php 
                    foreach($catAllArray as $catAllRow) {
                        if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Category\" value=\"".$catAllRow."\" checked=\"checked\" />".$catAllRow."&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
                        }   
                        else if(in_array($catAllRow,$catArray)) {
                            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Category\" value=\"".$catAllRow."\" checked=\"checked\" />".$catAllRow."&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Category\" value=\"".$catAllRow."\" />".$catAllRow."&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
                        }   
                    }   
                ?>
            </fieldset> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form> <!-- End: filter -->
    </div>  <!-- End: filters -->
```

From here the original code continues to output results into a table but this works properly and I don't think it is the problem. I can share more if asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the submit button a name, if that's what you're using to check if the form is submitted...

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

Or if you dont want to change the submit button, you can check isset on the category input instead

```
if(isset($_POST['Category'])){echo"SET";} else{echo"NOT SET";}
```

Comment: You were absolutely correct! by adding a button name and by changing the input name from Category to Category[] the page works perfectly. Thank you JoeTomato and everyone else for your quick and helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your check if there is a _POST value is wrong. try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['FiscalYear']))
```

And see if that works

Answer (score 1):

you need to name your submit button if you want to check for it

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

otherwise php will not place it in the $_POST array